# Getting an empty array from mongodb while executing the find query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Thanks in advance, Why I am getting an empty array from the Mongodb even though using the  correct  schema  name?

````
const Mongoose = require("mongoose");   
const studentSchema = Mongoose.Schema({
  _id: { type: Number, required: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true, max: 30 },
  department: { type: String, required: true,max: 30 },
  type: { type: String, required: true, min: 7, max: 30 }
});
module.exports = Mongoose.model("StudentInformation", studentSchema);
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
class  Service {
  static get() {
    const data = studentsModel.find({}).then((result) => {
        console.log(studentsModel)
      return result;
    });
    return data;
  }
}
----------------------------------------------------------------------

```
> db.getCollectionNames();
[ "StudentInformation", "students" ]
> db.StudentInformation.find();
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "selva", "department" : "CSE", "type" : "regular" }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "ashik", "department" : "CSE", "type" : "regular" }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "praveen", "department" : "CSE", "type" : "parttime" }
````

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong "return" instruction in your get() function:

```
 static get() {
    const data = studentsModel.find({}).then((result) => {
        console.log(studentsModel)
      return result;
    });
    **return data;**
  }
```

This part is asynchrone

```
studentsModel.find({}).then((result) => {
```

Your returning data which is empty / undefined before the execution of the find callback

Comment: Thanks @Daphoque I am getting now why it returns the empty array.